# how to get file name using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, shutil

I have a python script that list folders and files in a given path i want to find a **pdf file** that that start with number and with the current date. For this i used regular expression but the problem is that the system does not match the requested file.

```
regular expression = [0-9]+_[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$
```

example of file name  : 10204_09-03-2021.pdf

where is the error in my code ?

## code:

```
for file in files:
   if file.endwith("pdf"):
      if file == re.findall("^[0-9]+_[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$",file)
         shutil.copy(filename,destination)
```

Comment: $ means the match must end at the end of the line.  What about `.pdf`?  End with `\.pdf$` instead.

Comment: add .pdf to the end of the regex

Comment: i tried your comment but still did not find it

Comment: Probably because you're doing `file == re.findall(...)`. File is a string and re.findall() will return a list in this case.

Comment: What is `filename`? Shouldn't it be a `file` here?

Answer (score 0):

When your file name is `10204_09-03-2021.pdf`. Your regex pattern won't match it because it's supposed to end with `[0-9]{2}$` because of the $. But your file name will be 10204_09-03-2021.pdf, so it will always end with `.pdf`.

Adding a .pdf between and `[0-9]{2}` and `$` will match it. E.g -

```
>>> import re
>>> file = "10204_09-03-2021.pdf"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"[0-9]+_[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}\.pdf$")
>>> pattern.findall(file)
['10204_09-03-2021.pdf']
```

Also note that in `file == re.findall(...)` file is a string and re.findall(...) is a list. So you'll get a False even if it matches. You can try using [re.fullmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) which returns a [Match Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) (where boolean value is always True) or None if it doesn't match. Or, you can do `file in re.findall(...)`

Comment: still did not find the requested file

Comment: Is it that your file name doesn't match or something else? Because this pattern should.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import os, re, shutil
destination = r'new/folder/path'
files = ['folder/10204_09-03-2021.pdf', 'folder/04_09-03-2021.pdf']
rx = re.compile(r'^[0-9]+_[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}\.pdf$', re.I)
for file in files:
    if rx.match(os.path.basename(file)):
        #shutil.copy(filename,destination)
        print(file) # Just print here
# => folder/10204_09-03-2021.pdf, folder/04_09-03-2021.pdf
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/B0CXcT) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7rhXLm/2).

**NOTE**: The regex is applied only to the basename of the file path (the file name itself, with extension). Thus, the `\.pdf` is added to the regex pattern, and `^`/`$` anchors make sure the entire string must match the regex. Using `re.match` here yields the same results as `re.search` or `re.fullmatch`.

*Regex details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `_` - a `_` char
- `[0-3]?[0-9]` - an optional digit from `0` to `3` and then any one digit
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-3]?[0-9]-`  - an optional digit from `0` to `3` and then any one digit and then a hyphen
- `(?:[0-9]{2})?` - an optional sequence of two digits
- `[0-9]{2}` - two digits
- `\.pdf` - `.pdf` string
- `$` - end of string.

The regex is case insensitive due to `re.I` flag.